# time.strftime not updating in while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to record live streams.  I want to periodically check if the stream is live and then record with streamlink and save the file with a unique date/time.

```py
from subprocess import call
import sys
import time

streamURL = str(sys.argv[1])
streamQuality = str(sys.argv[2])
streamName = str(sys.argv[3])


streamBuilder = []
streamBuilder.append("streamlink")
streamBuilder.append(streamURL)
streamBuilder.append(streamQuality)
streamBuilder.append("-o")
streamBuilder.append("/download/"+streamName+"-"+time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+".mkv")

while True:
    call(streamBuilder)
    time.sleep(60)
```

With the current code, the name does not change each time the stream is live.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change the laste value of the streamBuilder at each iteration

```
while True:
    call(streamBuilder)
    time.sleep(60)
    streamBuilder[-1] = "/download/"+streamName+"-"+time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+".mkv"
```